# Apply "any" or "all" function row-wise to arbitrary number of Boolean columns in Julia DataFrames.jl

Tags: dataframe, julia, dataframes.jl

Suppose I have a dataframe with multiple boolean columns representing certain conditions:

```
df = DataFrame(
         id = ["A", "B", "C", "D"], 
         cond1 = [true, false, false, false], 
         cond2 = [false, false, false, false], 
         cond3 = [true, false, true, false]
)
```

|  | id | cond1 | cond2 | cond3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | C | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | D | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Now suppose I want to identify rows where any of these conditions are true, ie "A" and "C". It is easy to do this explicitly:

```
df[:, :all] = df.cond1 .| df.cond2 .| df.cond3
```

But how can this be done when there are an arbitrary number of conditions, for example something like:

```
df[:, :all] = any.([ df[:, Symbol("cond$i")] for i in 1:3 ])
```

The above fails with `DimensionMismatch("tried to assign 3 elements to 4 destinations")` because the `any` function is being applied column-wise, rather than row-wise. So the real question is: how to apply `any` row-wise to multiple Boolean columns in a dataframe?

The ideal output should be:

|  | id | cond1 | cond2 | cond3 | all |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | C | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | D | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(
                id = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
                cond1 = [true, false, false, false, true],
                cond2 = [false, false, false, false, true],
                cond3 = [true, false, true, false, true]
       )
5×4 DataFrame
 Row │ id      cond1  cond2  cond3
     │ String  Bool   Bool   Bool
─────┼─────────────────────────────
   1 │ A        true  false   true
   2 │ B       false  false  false
   3 │ C       false  false   true
   4 │ D       false  false  false
   5 │ E        true   true   true

julia> transform(df, AsTable(r"cond") .=> ByRow.([maximum, minimum]) .=> [:any, :all])
5×6 DataFrame
 Row │ id      cond1  cond2  cond3  any    all
     │ String  Bool   Bool   Bool   Bool   Bool
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ A        true  false   true   true  false
   2 │ B       false  false  false  false  false
   3 │ C       false  false   true   true  false
   4 │ D       false  false  false  false  false
   5 │ E        true   true   true   true   true
```

Note that it is quite fast even for very wide tables:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(rand(Bool, 10_000, 10_000), :auto);

julia> @time transform(df, AsTable(r"x") .=> ByRow.([maximum, minimum]) .=> [:any, :all]);
  0.059275 seconds (135.41 k allocations: 103.038 MiB)
```

In the examples I have used a regex column selector, but of course you can use any row selector you like.

Comment: Thanks. One way I just thought of which also works is: ```df[:, :all] = vec(any(Matrix(select(df, r"cond")), dims=2))```, but it is perhaps not as idiomatic as your solution.

Comment: It works, but for large data frames it will be slower and allocate much more memory (in my large test - it is 8x smaller and allocates 200x more memory).